# SmsManager performed several times

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm trying to send multiple SMS messages.
My code:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : book.entrySet()) {
    sendSMS(entry.getValue(), message);
}
```

sendSMS:

```
private void sendSMS(final String phoneNumber, String message) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    System.out.println("sent");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    System.out.println("No network "+ phoneNumber);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
    }
```

But the cases are performed several times. For 4 contcts:

1. No network 123456879
2. No network 123456879
3. No network +79206501013
4. No network 123456879
5. No network +79206501013
6. No network +79206501012
7. No network 123456879
8. No network +79206501013
9. No network +79206501012
10. No network 987654321

What could be the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think moving the registerReceiver(...) outside of sendSMS will solve this. This seems to be a case of multiple registrations.

Try something like this

```
Intent smsSentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
smsSentIntent.setClass(context, SmsSentBroadcastReceiver.class);
```

Comment: Thanks!But can you give an example SmsSentBroadcastReceiver.class?

Comment: Thats any BroadcastReceiver you wish to handle the SMS_SENT intent. You can use the code in your registerReceiver(...) just put it into a separate class.

Comment: ofc! But while i cant up reputation( Sorry

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)